# Finding string between 2 specific character

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of directories:

```
C:\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7
```

I need a way to extract `"level4"` and `"level5"`.

Aka. I need to extract the string between the 4th and 5th backlash and the string between the 5th and 6th backslash.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting by **backslash**:

```
s = "C:\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7"
l = s.split('\\')
print l[4], l[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> s = r'C:\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7'
>>> words = s.split('\\') # Escape backslash or use rawstring -  r'\'
>>> words[4]
'level4'
>>> words[5]
'level5'
```

If you want to join those two words, then use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> ' '.join((words[4],words[5]))
'level4 level5'
```

Also if you want a list of levels,

```
>>> ' '.join(words[i] for i in [4,5,6])
'level4 level5 level6'
```

Comment: `s = r'C:\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7'`

Comment: @FunkySayu Yep. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split a string according to a specific delimiter.

```
path = r'C:\level1\level2\level3\level4\level5\level6\level7'
dirs  = path.split('\\')

print dirs[4], dirs[5]
# will print:
# level4 level5
```